# Interface between recyclerview adapter & viewholder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

So I have a Recyclerview & multiple viewholders. Now one of my viewholder contains an item that has few animations. Now if a user clicks on the item activity opens and I have no control over the activity, the only way I got to know is via the callback in my fragment i.e onPause & onResume. I want to call `animation.onResume()` once my fragment `onResume()` is invoked.

Interface class

```
interface CustomTabClosedListener {
        fun onCustomTabClosed()
    }
```

**Adapter Relevant code:**

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   lateinit var viewViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
   val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
   val view = layoutInflater!!.inflate(R.layout.feed_coverage, parent, false)
                viewViewHolder = CoverageViewHolder(view)
                listener = viewViewHolder
}
```

where listener is `private var listener: CustomTabClosedListener?=null`

**ViewHolder**

```
class CoverageViewHolder(val view: View) :CustomTabClosedListener {

override fun onCustomTabClosed() {
    animation?.resume()
```

Now my fragment calls this adapter method in onResume -

```
fun customTabClosed() {
    listener?.onCustomTabClosed()
 }
```

But here my listener is getting `null` and I don't know the reason why. How can i invoke my method in viewholder via my adapter/fragment? Is there any other better approach?

Comment: Maybe `onResume` called before `onCreateViewHolder`?

Comment: @PavelPoley I am clicking the item of that view holder itself. So onResume is called afterward

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason why you get null is because you should have only a single call back in the `Adapter` `viewHolder`, and all the animation should be managed by the view. Is better and clean if the adapter manage some really elementar business logic, leaving what should happen to the view into the view itself.

Let's say you have an xml file with your animation
you could have from the view the control to notify the adapter and start the animation

```
fun IamACoolCallBack(){

 AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation_fall_down);
with(recyclerView){
    setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    scheduleLayoutAnimation();
 }
}
```

EDIT
I found [this](https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213) tutorial it looks pretty neat to me

Comment: more or less I am trying to do the same thing. View inside viewholder manages all the state, except resume & I am unable to notify my viewholder about the resume state

Comment: eventually you can make it work from the ViewHolder, but you ask if there is a better approach, and I would endorse the one I suggested you, leaving to the activity all the responsibility to manage lifecycle and the animation effect. I am going to suggest you a good tutorial in my edit